# Increase the height / padding of the MenuBarExtra .menu button in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, styling, menubar

I've been frustrated for some time now trying to figure out how to increase the height of the button in the MenuBarExtra menu for a MacOS app. I've seen another app that has a larger height on these buttons, but I've been unable to replicate the same style nor have I found anything similar on the web.

This is what I have so far. Tried out applying different `MenuBarExtraStyle` to it, but what I need is a `.menu` style which is of a type `PullDownMenuBarExtraStyle`.

```
MenuBarExtra("Settings", systemImage: "hammer") {
     Button(action: {}) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "pawprint.fill")
                    Text("Small Button")
                }
            }
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.menu)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to `.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)` you have full control over the display sizes and can build your own menu there.

```
        MenuBarExtra("Settings", systemImage: "hammer") {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Label("Larger Button", systemImage: "pawprint.fill")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                }
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
                .padding()
            }
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's the way at the moment.